# why is my GUI health bar draining from both directions instead of from only 1 direction?

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine, direction

I imagine it's because I didn't tell it through code which direction I want it draining from, but I thought that was already obvious to unity since that's the setting I have on the GUI Image Type in the hierarchy is filled and the Fill Origin is set to left. Regardless, I assume that something in my code is telling it to drain from both sides maybe?? my life bars are draining from both sides but I only want it draining from the left. Does anyone have any solutions?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class meterDrain : MonoBehaviour {

public float maxHungerMeter = 100f;
public float curHungerMeter;
public RectTransform hungerMeter;

public float maxThirstMeter = 100f;
public float curThirstMeter;
public RectTransform thirstMeter;

public float maxEnergyMeter = 100f;
public float curEnergyMeter;
public RectTransform EnergyMeter;

public float maxBowelsMeter = 100f;
public float curBowelsMeter;
public RectTransform bowelsMeter;

public float maxMoraleMeter = 100f;
public float curMoraleMeter;
public RectTransform moraleMeter;


void Start () 
{
    curHungerMeter = maxHungerMeter;    
    curThirstMeter = maxThirstMeter;
    curEnergyMeter = maxEnergyMeter;
    curBowelsMeter = maxBowelsMeter;
    curMoraleMeter = maxMoraleMeter;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update ()
{
    TakeDamage ();
}

void TakeDamage(float amount = 10f){    //as of now the meters are being drained towards the middle from both sides. need to fix that
    {
        curHungerMeter -= amount * Time.deltaTime;
        curThirstMeter -= amount * Time.deltaTime;
        curEnergyMeter -= amount * Time.deltaTime;
        curBowelsMeter -= amount * Time.deltaTime;
        curMoraleMeter -= amount * Time.deltaTime;
    }

    if (hungerMeter == null)    //for some reason, this is being applied all meters besides hunger, even though i didn't tell it to. *shrugs* works for me.
        return;

    hungerMeter.sizeDelta = new Vector2 (curHungerMeter, hungerMeter.sizeDelta.y);
    thirstMeter.sizeDelta = new Vector2 (curHungerMeter, thirstMeter.sizeDelta.y);
    EnergyMeter.sizeDelta = new Vector2 (curHungerMeter, EnergyMeter.sizeDelta.y);
    bowelsMeter.sizeDelta = new Vector2 (curHungerMeter, bowelsMeter.sizeDelta.y);
    moraleMeter.sizeDelta = new Vector2 (curHungerMeter, moraleMeter.sizeDelta.y);



}
}



//The edited script that now works...

using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class meterDrain : MonoBehaviour {

private float drainTime = 10f;
private float maxHungerMeter = 100f;
public float curHungerMeter;
public Image hungerMeter;

private float maxThirstMeter = 100f;
public float curThirstMeter;
public Image thirstMeter;

private float maxEnergyMeter = 100f;
public float curEnergyMeter;
public Image energyMeter;

private float maxBowelsMeter = 100f;
public float curBowelsMeter;
public Image bowelsMeter;

private float maxMoraleMeter = 100f;
public float curMoraleMeter;
public Image moraleMeter;


void Start () 
{
    curHungerMeter = maxHungerMeter;    
    curThirstMeter = maxThirstMeter;
    curEnergyMeter = maxEnergyMeter;
    curBowelsMeter = maxBowelsMeter;
    curMoraleMeter = maxMoraleMeter;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update ()
{
    TakeDamage ();
}

void TakeDamage(float amount = 10f){    
    {
        curHungerMeter -= amount * Time.deltaTime;
        curThirstMeter -= amount * Time.deltaTime;
        curEnergyMeter -= amount * Time.deltaTime;
        curBowelsMeter -= amount * Time.deltaTime;
        curMoraleMeter -= amount * Time.deltaTime;
    }

    if (hungerMeter == null) {
        return;
    }
        else
        {
            hungerMeter.fillAmount -= 1.0f / drainTime * Time.deltaTime;
    }

    if (thirstMeter == null) {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        thirstMeter.fillAmount -= 1.0f / drainTime * Time.deltaTime;
    }

    if (energyMeter == null){
        return;
    }   
    else
    {
        energyMeter.fillAmount -= 1.0f / drainTime * Time.deltaTime;
    }

    if (bowelsMeter == null){ 
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        bowelsMeter.fillAmount -= 1.0f / drainTime * Time.deltaTime;
    }

    if (moraleMeter == null){ 
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        moraleMeter.fillAmount -= 1.0f / drainTime * Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Where is the code that draws your health bars to the screen?

Comment: it's a gui in unity. The RecTransform at the top is where I place the health bar into the RecTransform*name*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're changing the size of your health bar by setting its RectTransform, instead you want to change the Image component's [Fill Amount](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Image-fillAmount.html). For this to work you'll need to change the type of your meter objects (hungerMeter etc.) to type Image.

Comment: Ohhh is that the reason??? But if i do that, " hungerMeter.sizeDelta = new Vector2 (curHungerMeter, hungerMeter.sizeDelta.y); " doesn't work, along with the other meters, since sizeDelta doesn't work with Image.

Comment: You need change the Image value's fill amount, as written in the documentation. Also since the fill amount has a range of 0 to 1, you'll need to change your logic a bit.

Comment: okay. ur feedback helped me enough for me to get it straightened out. thanks!

Comment: No worries! Glad it helped.

Comment: Also having a look at your edited code, why not write 
if (hungerMeter != null) hungerMeter.fillAmount -= 1.0f / drainTime * Time.deltaTime;?
it'll save you some space and make the code more readable, unless you really want to return out of the method when the Image is set to null. Although I don't think it ever should be null if you're setting the field in the Inspector!

Comment: well that's what I tried doing originally, but it only worked for the first meter (the hungerMeter). But the others became non-responsive and stopped draining. I put it that way because it was the only way the others worked also. I don't know why the code only checks that first line and stops after that. If you got any ideas why feel free to explain it or how to solve it.

Comment: it was exactly how you suggested, so it looked like, " (hungerMeter != null) hungerMeter.fillAmount -= 1.0f / drainTime * Time.deltaTime  ." But I had it set for the other ones too. such as, (thirstMeter != null) thirstMeter.fillAmount -= 1.0f / drainTime * Time.deltaTime , and so on and so forth. But it only worked for the first one, hungerMeter. The other meters after the first one, hungerMeter, were nonresponsive and didn't drain at all in anyway with that version.